# Why do I have to return a function that returns a promise to assign the result in the then method?

Tags: javascript

I have an object (SoapClient) with a function (createClient) that returns a promise which is either resolved or rejected. The fulfilled value of the promise is a client. I'm trying to call SoapClient.createClient and in the 'then' method, assign the fulfilled promise value to my local client variable, but it is not working unless I return the function. Can someone explain why? Thanks. Here's my code:

SoapClient module:

```
const soap = require('some soap library').soap;

module.exports = {
  createClient: (options) => {
    const { option1, option2, option3, option4 } = options;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!option1 || !option2) {
        reject('some error message');
      }

      soap.createClient(option3, {endpoint: option4}, (err, client) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }

        //some code to set authentication here

        resolve(client);
      })
    });
  }
};
```

some test class:

```
before(() => {
  let soapClient;
  const options = { option1: 'something', option2: 'something', option3: 'something', option4: 'something' }

  return SoapClient.createClient(options)
    .then((client) => {
      soapClient = client;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
});
```

In this case, soapClient is correctly assigned the fulfilled promise value of client, but if I remove the return, then soapClient becomes undefined. Why is this? Is there any way to assign soapClient the correct value without the return? Thanks.

Comment: Is this code in a function?  Why do you have a `return` there?  Also, remember that promises are *asynchronous*, so your `soapClient` will *not* be set *until* `createClient()` is done and `.then` is called.

Comment: looks like problem in other place. Is this code of function ? In what way do you check variable soapClient ? looks like you call function without return statement and got undefined

Comment: @Sabik: Good point.  Removing the `return` would mean wherever this function is called would be getting an `undefined` value.

Comment: @user2017502 See [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://gist.github.com/3889970)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I updated post with more code.

Answer (score 0):

This will return two alerts:

```
var SoapClient = {
  createClient: function() {
    return Promise.resolve(true)
    .then(function(x) {
        return 'client';
    });
  },
  createClient1: function() {
    return Promise.resolve('client');
  }
}

SoapClient.createClient()
    .then(function(client) {
        alert(client);
    });
SoapClient.createClient1()
    .then(function(client) {
        alert(client);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which `return` the `Promise` value or rejection reason. Get value at chained `.then()`

```
let getClient = (options) => {

  const options = Object.assign({ option1: 'something', option2: 'something' }, options);

  return SoapClient.createClient(options)
         .then(client => client)
         .catch((err) => {
           throw new Error(err);
         });
}

let soapClient = getClient(/* {option1:"abc"} */);

soapClient.then(success, err);
```

Comment: I'm trying to work out what functionality the `then` and the `catch` are attempting  here.